# Install Jupyter notebook offline

Tags: python, jupyter

I have a Linux machine that cannot access the internet and I need to install the Jupyter notebook on it, without root privileges. I can copy whatever files to my machine and them copy those files to the remote machine. How can I get all dependencies and install them, without using Anaconda, for example? Pip is ok.

Comment: And please, if the downvotes are coming, please enlighten-me with docs that point how to solve this problem, or to move it to a more appropriate forum. Thanks.

Comment: without root privileges: definitely virtualenv. but you'll have to manually satisy dependencies

Comment: Yes, but where can I find the dependency list?

Comment: Anaconda has IPython notebook and can be installed without root priv's.  From Anaconda you can also use Pip for installations if that is available to you.  Why exclude it in your question?

Comment: anaconda will consume a lot of space. maybe, that's why..

Comment: Also there are a few licensing side effects with Anaconda that I have to consider.

Answer (score 4):

**warning**: this answer might fail in future due to a possible deprecation in `--relocatable` option in virtualenv

idea: create a *relocatable* virtualenv in another computer, install jupyter in there, and tar and move it to the said linux machine, untar it, and profit

Nb. To install virtualenv, run `pip install virtualenv`

step 1: create a virtualenv

```
$ virtualenv .venv
```

step 2: activate .venv

```
$ . .venv/bin/activate
```

step 3: install jupyter

```
$ pip install jupyter
```

step 4: mark .venv as [relocatable](https://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide.html#making-environments-relocatable)

```
$ virtualenv --relocatable .venv
```

step 5: tar the .venv directory

```
$ tar czfv venv.tgz .venv/
```

step 6: move to offline linux machine, and untar

```
$ tar xvzf venv.tgz
```

step 7: activate virtualenv to use it

```
$ . .venv/bin/activate
```

Comment: Great idea! And even if the packing up doesn't work, OP can sill get a list of all required packages via `pip freeze` in that virtualenv and then downloading them by hand.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone still gets the following error:

```
-bash: ./.venv/bin/jupyter-notebook: /home/hhoward/.venv/bin/python2.7: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

(To add to Ayush's answer)

It is important to run the relocatable command AFTER the jupyter installation.

```
pip install jupyter
virtualenv --relocatable .venv
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use another Linux machine with internet access to pack jupyter and his dependencies and then move it to your machine and install it.

1. On internet access machine create `tar.gz` file:

```
mkdir jupyter
cd jupyter
pip download jupyter
cd ..
tar -czvf jupyter.tar.gz /jupyter
```

2. Move the created `jupyter.tar.gz` file to your machine using external hard drive.
3. On your machine install the `jupyter.tar.gz` file:

```
tar -zxvf jupyter.tar.gz
pip install jupyter --no-index --find-links=./jupyter
```

4. Check that everything work well with:

```
jupyter notebook --ip 0.0.0.0 --port 9999 --allow-root
```

** If you wanna use **Jupyterlab** instead Jupyter-notebook replace this two lines:

a. replace `pip download jupyter` with `pip download jupyterlab`.

b. replace `jupyter notebook --ip 0.0.0.0 --port 9999 --allow-root` with `jupyter lab --ip 0.0.0.0 --port 9999 --allow-root`.