# Migrate third party modules in python from one machine to another

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

Is there a way (list of manual steps) to migrate 3rd party modules installed in one python installation on one machine to another machine?

This would be of great help to me because I have installed the list of 3rd party modules in one of my machines (using `pip` tool) and I want to migrate this setup to another machine where I cannot install using `pip` (due to network restrictions).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33894313/install-jupyter-notebook-offline/33894905#33894905

Comment: try this, http://aptoncd.sourceforge.net/ is convert all apt file to iso image.

Comment: @i'mPosSible why not use virtualenv instead? downloading whole repo is overkill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [schlamar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/851737/schlamar) said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11034515/5080583):

> Here is a completely different suggestion, this is recommended if you
>   want to synchronize the packages between the two PCs and not cloning
>   everything just once.
>
> It only works if you install packages with [pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/). It does not work for
>   packages which are not installable/installed with pip.
>
> Set up the pip cache to a network storage / USB stick which is accessible from both PCs (see [https://stackoverflow.com/a/4806458/851737](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4806448/how-do-i-install-from-a-local-cache-with-pip/4806458#4806458) for instructions)
>
> Freeze your current package environment from the source PC into a requirements file:
>
> `$ pip freeze > req.txt`
>
> Copy the req file to the target PC and install the packages:
>
> `$ pip install -r req.txt`
>
> If you put the req.txt under a VCS you can automate and synchronize
>   this process very smoothly.