# How to use virtualenv to run python code

Tags: pip, virtualenv

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33894905/6456477), I create a virtualenv and I send it to my server, which is offline. Using this approach to solve the package installation problem.

But after I activate the virtualenv in the server, `pip show` still shows the former packages not the packages installed in virtualenv.

How to solve it? Anyone could help?

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
virtualenv dirname
```

to create a virtual environment.And then to activate it
use

```
source dirname/bin/activate
```

to activate the virtual environment. You can use it then `python file name`. You can use pip .

Comment: I just did like this. And I indeed activated the virtualenv because it showed `(envname) ubuntu@mycomputer`.  But when I `python mypy.py`, it still showed I don't have the package.  (ps: my server can't use internet so I can't use pip.)